# Adding value to Postgres integer array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am looking for help in adding a value `10` to an `int[]` in PostgreSQL 9.5.

Looking at the documentation I should be able to use this format to update it but it is not working:

```
int[] + int   push element onto array (add it to end of array)
```

I have tried running this:

```
update table1 set integer_array = integer_array + 10::Integer.
```

It did not work and I got this error:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer[] + integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 67
```

I feel this is the same format like the one presented in the documentation on  how to perform this operation.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use `array_append` function to append an element at the end of an array:

```
UPDATE table1
SET integer_array = array_append(integer_array, 5);
```

5 is a value of choice, it's of an integer datatype in your case. You probably need some `WHERE` clause as well not to update the entire table.

Try below to see how it works:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,2], array_append(ARRAY[1,2],3);
```

Result:

```
 array | array_append
-------+--------------
 {1,2} | {1,2,3}
```

Answer (score 21):

I like this way better:

```
UPDATE table1 SET integer_array = integer_array || '{10}';
```

You can also add multiple values with single query:

```
UPDATE table1 SET integer_array = integer_array || '{10, 11, 12}';
```

Answer (score 10):

single:

```
UPDATE table1
SET integer_array = array_append(integer_array, 3);
```

multiple:

```
UPDATE table1
SET integer_array = array_cat(integer_array, ARRAY[4,5]);
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE

Answer (score 8):

```
-- Declaring the array

arrayName int8[];

-- Adding value 2206 to int array

arrayName := arrayName || 2206;

-- looping throught the array

FOREACH i IN ARRAY arrayName 
LOOP 

 RAISE NOTICE 'array value %', i;

END LOOP;
```

cheers